# When to use "to workspace" block vs "outport" block

Tags: matlab, simulink

I can use both blocks for getting output from simulink to matlab, but if there are two of them there should be difference in the way they are used but I can not figure it out.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using an [Outport](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/outport.html) block allows you to,

- use your model as a [Model Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/model-reference.html)
- when generating code (using Simulink Coder) from the model, interface the model with other code

If you're not needing to do either of the above - for instance you only want to dump data to the MATLAB Workspace - then the [To Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block is arguably easier to use.  Plus it shows the user what the resulting variable will be without them having to open the model properties window.

Note also that [To Workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) can be used at any level of model hierarchy, whereas [Outport](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/outport.html) can only be used to get data out of the highest level of a model. ([Outport](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/outport.html) are used in [SubSystems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/codereusesubsystem.html) but to interface a sub-level of a model to a higher level, not to get data out of the model.)